# Possible? $add values of array to compare with object total value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> mongodb native for node.js (driver version is 2.2.4 and MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9)

My collection has objects like this:

```
{x:[{v:0.002},{v:0.00002}],t:0.00202} //<this one has the full total in its values

{x:[{v:0.002},{v:0.002}],t:0.00202}

{x:[{v:0.002},{v:0.002}],t:0.3}
```

*(shown here without their object ids)*

I am unsure how to add up all the `x.v` to return only objects where the total of `x.v` is greater or equal to the objects `t`

```
aggregate({"t":{"$gte":{"$add":["x.v"]}}})
```

returns every object, I don't have any other idea on the order of syntax from reading the docs.

Can mongodb even do this in a query?

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: driver version is 2.2.4 and MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB 3.2, a couple of approaches you can take here. You can query with the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$where": function() {
        return (this.x.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b.v;
        }, 0) > this.t);
    }
})
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587107b3cbe62793a0f14e74"),
    "x" : [ 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }
    ],
    "t" : 0.00202
}
```

But note this is bound to be a not very efficient solution since a query operation with the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator calls the JavaScript engine to evaluate JavaScript code on every document and checks the condition for each.

This is very slow as MongoDB evaluates non-**[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** query operations before **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** expressions and non-**[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** query statements may use an index.

It is advisable to combine with indexed queries if you can so that the query may be faster. However, it's strongly recommended to use JavaScript expressions and the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator as a last resort when you can't structure the data in any other way, or when you are dealing with a small subset of data.

---

A better approach would be to use the aggregation framework where you can use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to flatten the array `x`, calculate the sums for `x.v` within a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline and subsequently filtering the documents using the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline stage. This allows you to proccess the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition is false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$x" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "x": { "$push": "$x" },
            "t": { "$first": "$t" },
            "y": { "$sum": "$x.v" }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$y", "$t" ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }           
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587107b3cbe62793a0f14e74"),
    "x" : [ 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }
    ],
    "t" : 0.00202,
    "y" : 0.004
}
```

However, as much as this solution is better than the previous solution that uses **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)**, bear in mind that the use of **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator can also limit performance with larger datasets since it produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process.

Also, this solution requires knowledge of the document fields since this is needed in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline where you retain the fields in the grouping process by using the accumulators like **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**. That can be a huge limitation if your query needs to be dynamic.

---

For the most efficient solution, I would suggest bumping your MongoDB server to 3.4, and use the combination of the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline stage and the new **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** array operator to filter the documents in a seamless manner.

The **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** is for calculating the sum of the `x.v` fields in the array by applying an expression to each element in an array and combining them into a single value.

You can then use this an an expression with the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline's evaluation to get the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$gt": [ 
                        {
                            "$reduce": {
                                "input": "$x",
                                "initialValue": 0,
                                "in": { "$add": ["$$value", "$$this.v"] }
                            }
                        }, 
                        "$t" 
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }           
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587107b3cbe62793a0f14e74"),
    "x" : [ 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 0.002
        }
    ],
    "t" : 0.00202
}
```